# How to create or find the API key for Azure Application Insight?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created a free account on Azure and created a new instance for Application Insight. My idea was to log errors from my asp.net web API project. I am planning to manually configure my web API to use this instance of app insight. For this, I need to have an API key to connect to app Insight. I followed this documentation https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID to find it. But when I clicked the settings, I don't see any link for "Create API Key". I have created several new instances and nowhere I could find the API key. The only thing I could find was the Subscription ID.

Comment: The API keys are for querying data from the App Insights API. To log errors, telemetry, messages, etc, you only need the instrumentation key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application insights instance -> API Access -> Create API key

[image]

Comment: I think @Kin asked about ingestion part rather than query. For this they need an instrumentation key rather than API key.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it's true @Kin doesn't know where or how to create an API key.

Comment: @Kin if you are trying to integrate your app with azure app insights, with code-based way, see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-visual-studio) and with codeless way, see [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#enable-application-insights).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new Key, if you have already created an Application insights, you just need to navigate to the Instance

**`Open -> Goto Overview Blade -> Copy the Instrumentation key`**

[image]

Comment: But if I want to log errors from my web API, I need it to use it on my application config file

Comment: yeah you can use the same key

Comment: +1. @Kim, your link is talking about query part of Application Insights, not about ingestion. For ingestion you need an Instrumentation Key.